# check if a server socket is open on the other side

Tags: java, sockets

I would check if a server socket placed in the server is open. In the client when I create the socket `Socket sock = new Socket(host,port)` I check if it's open doing:

```
if(sock == null)
    System.out.println("The server is not connected!");
else
    //Doing some task
```

but i don't receive any result. there is method to check if the server socket at on the other side is open? I tried even the method `isConnected()` but nothing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the server is not listening you will get an Connection Refused in an exception.  You will **never** get a null from a `new`

Answer (score 11):

The simplest way to check reachability and liveness is to create a blank `Socket` and use the `connect()`  method with a reasonable timeout. I wrote a similar answer with a small [code snippet here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/406567/1735700#post1735700).